# Edit Python code for converting decimal number to binary

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

i have this code that convert dec to bin using bitwise operators, and it work correctly.
if i delete line 5(`if(m&n)`). What changes I need to make to the code to work correctly again?(I have to delete `if command` somehow that doesn't interfere with the code working)

Comment: Is this some sort of homework question? Otherwise if it ain't broke, don't fix it.

Comment: yes. it is a homework

Comment: Then you have learned nothing, some kind contributors here have done it for you. Before asking questions like this in future please read the [guidelines on homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions). By the way, your edit a few minutes ago now makes your question unintelligible as we've no idea what you are talking about, what line 5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace it by just inserting the value `1 * (m&n > 0)` (or `0 + (m&n > 0)`):

```
def DecToBin(n):
    m = 1
    binary = list()
    while m <= n:
        binary.insert(0, 1 * (m&n > 0))
        # or, binary.insert(0, 0 + (m&n > 0))
        m = m << 1
    return binary

print(DecToBin(7))
print(DecToBin(8))
```

Output:

```
[1, 1, 1]
[1, 0, 0, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `bin()` function?

Comment: i must edit this code, not using of built in function or method!

Comment: Point is it's a homework type question, and you haven't even googled a bit before asking it.